# Как объявить интерфейс с вложенными уровнями?

Tags: angular2, typescript

У меня в скрипте есть набор пользователей. Для них я объявляю такой интерфейс:

```
export interface User {
    fields: Object;
    model: string;
    pk: number;
}
```

[Вот пример](https://i.yapx.ru/gqMP.png) данных реального пользователя. Как видите в том, что я выше объявил как `fields: Object` есть вложенность. Однако она не описана в моём интерфейсе.

Поскажите пожалуйста как её описать.

Пожалуйста не предлагайте мне пересобрать объект. Мне интересен именно случай вложенных свойств.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface UserFields {
  created: Date;
  login: string;
}

export interface User {
    fields: UserFields;
    model: string;
    pk: number;
}
```

или

```
export interface User {
  fields: {
    created: Date;
    login: string;
  };

  model: string;
  pk: number;
}
```